# What do content addresses look like in Umbraco?

Tags: razor, localhost, umbraco

I was trying to access content through previews. At first, this was fine with both Preview and non-preview views, but I moved some of my code to another branch and noticed issues. I remembered seeing http://localhost:63761/1120 work, but now: I'm not sure if this is the correct form of address for content under 1120 to appear. Is there something I need to check?

Answer (score 1):

Postfixing your url with an id is a quick way to look up the content of a node:

For example the following url works in my environment, but is not user or search engine friendly https://localhost:44392/1141

When I look up the node in my umbraco backend: https://localhost:44392/umbraco#/content/content/edit/1141

Navigate to the Properties tab and look for "Link to document", that's the user friendly url for the node

Comment: Then it's definitely something I overridden in my settings that doesn't work. Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, the urls should be like below

Non-preview mode url - 
http://localhost:63761/umbraco#/content/content/edit/1120

Preview mode url - 
http://localhost:63761/umbraco/preview/?id=1120#?id=1120

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.